# Verification Methods in Entity

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am using Domain-Driven-Design have an entity called Menu, need to check if the item has up to three levels, the class is now as shown below:

```
 public class Menu : Entity
    {

        public virtual AreaMenu AreaMenu { get; set; }

        public virtual Menu MenuPai { get; set; }

        public string Title{ get; set; }

        public virtual Site Site { get; set; }

        public Status Status { get; set; }

        public byte StatusId
        {
            get { return (byte)Status; }
            set { Status = (Status)value; }
        }

        public bool VerifyLevels()
        {
            if (this.MenuPai == null || this.MenuPai.MenuPai == null || this.MenuPai.MenuPai.MenuPai == null || this.MenuPai.MenuPai.MenuPai.MenuPai == null)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This check levels  (`public bool VerifyLevels()`) , it is right to be here in the entity or is correct that it is in the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is right to put validations in your entity. On the other hand, you could call this validation from your repository Save method to validate before saving

E.g.

```
public class MenuRepository : IMenuRepository
{
    public bool Save(Menu menu)
    {
        if (!menu.VerifyLevels())
            return false;

        if (menu.ID == 0)
            context.Menus.AddObject(menu);
        else
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(menu, EntityState.Modified);
        context.SaveChanges();

        returns true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it, create validation in the repository and run the scan only when you save the current form when I load the entity even for a simple reading it scans

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your preference. Domain driven design is more a way of thinking than a way of doing.

Some people like to keep their entity model layer very lightweight and clean - and thus don't put any validation there.

In my personal opinion, entities are not DTOs (data transfer objects) and thus should not be anemic. I don't like anemic domain models because the detract from code reuse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model